# Rails routing with param issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

With this routing

```
get "/sp_app/(:js_action)/(:js_id)" => 'single_page#show'
```

and this URL with params

```
http://url.com/sp_app/templates/null/?a=1
```

I get this

> puts params.to_json
>
> {"?a":"1","controller":"single_page_content","action":"templates","id":"null"}

Why, oh why, is Rails including the question mark in that param?  If I do ?a=1&b=2 I get params keys "?a" and "b".

I am sure I am missing something obvious here, but any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have some other, similar route in there that is taking priority over this one? Or maybe some route that is mutating your urls? When I tried this on rails 5.2.1 on Osx and ruby 2.2.2 it worked like expected.

url: http://localhost:3000/sp_app/templates/null/?a=1
route:  get "/sp_app/(:js_action)/(:js_id)" => 'test#test'
params: {"a":"1","controller":"test","action":"test","js_action":"templates","js_id":"null"}. Try making this the first directive in your routes.rb file.

Comment: I was a complete idiot.  There way the SPA application work is that there is JS load based on the various URL parts, and JS href parser includes "?" in the search attribute.  I have flagged the question for removel.  My apologies

Comment: no worries, glad you figured it out :)